# CKEditor editor instance .lang is undefined?

Tags: ckeditor

Hi I am trying to make some changes to our implementation of CKEDITOR 3.6.2

by removing all but 2 options in the link target type dropdown that appears in the link dialog's target tab.

I tried to achieve this using the API but I am getting an error in the minified core ckeditor.js file in the dialog() method on this line X=S.lang.dir; where S is the editor.

The .lang property of the editor instance is undefined when doing CKEDITOR.dialog(editor, 'link'), when viewing debugging the "editor" object I don't see a lang object anywhere, so I'm not sure why this is missing? I didn't work on our original implementation but as far as I know we have only added 2 plugins and not changed the ckeditor core.

Here is my code:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[i];
    var dialogObj = CKEDITOR.dialog(editor, 'link');
    var linkDialogTargetField = dialogObj.getContentElement('target', 'linkTargetType');
    // API didn't seem to have a more efficient approach than clearing all and re-adding the one we want
    linkDialogTargetField.clear();
    linkDialogTargetField.add('notSet', '<not set>');
    linkDialogTargetField.add('_blank', 'New Window (_blank)');
}
```

I have managed to make my change without using the API properly by doing the below:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event
    // data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
    // interested on (the "Link" dialog).
    if (dialogName == 'link') {
        // Get a reference to the "Link target" tab.
        var targetTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('target');

        var targetField = targetTab.get('linkTargetType');
        // removing everything except the 1st (none set) & 3rd (new window) options from the dropdown
        targetField['items'].splice(1, 2);
        targetField['items'].splice(2, 3); // the array is reduced by splice, so we have to splice from [2] onwards not from [4]
    }
});
```

but I don't like this approach, does anyone have any ideas? or other ways to achieve the same result using the API?

Comment: The API to change contents of dialogs is your second example. The first one is not something that you'll see in any example or tutorial about CKEditor and I don't know why you think that that is the correct way.

Comment: Maybe because all the examples are out dated and I am going directly to the source http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using second approach and overwritten the dropdown items instead of splicing.